# Regex allow only datetime (h:m:s) or an integer

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex pattern that only accept datetime (eg: 01:02:00) or an integer (123456789), The datetime can accept optional leading zero i mean it can also allow 1:2:10

It should allow or disallow these inputs:

```
0123456789✅
0123456789 word❌
word❌
01:00:10✅
1:2:10✅
1:10❌
1:2:❌
1:❌
```

I tried this pattern but not working correctly:

```php
if (preg_match('~^[0-9:]*$|[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}~')) {
    //allowed
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/mRxBNu/1

Comment: A good regex for Date is here : https://ihateregex.io/expr/date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a regex alternation here:

```regex
^(?:\d+|\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})$
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```
^                            from the start of the input
(?:
    \d+                      match one or more digits
    |                        OR
    \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}  match an H:M:S timestamp
)
$                            end of the input
```

Comment: I think `\d` instead of `[0-9]` would be much clearer (they are equivalent in all ways)

Comment: @Julia I agree, at least from the point of view of not cluttering the actual answer.  But sometimes, I prefer using `[0-9]`, when character classes are being used in other parts of the pattern.

Comment: Your pattern also works, If you dont mind i marked another answer as best cuz it have less words :p

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following could work:

```
^\d\d?(?:\d*|:\d\d?:\d\d?)$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSginc/1)

- `^`  - Start string anchor.
- `\d\d?` - A single digit and an optional one.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\d*` - 0+ digits;
  - `|` - Or:
  - `:\d\d?:\d\d?` - A colon, digit and an optional digit (two times in a row).
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This regex will detect any date and a 10 digit Integer/Number

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^([0-9]{10})$
```

Inspired from here :

https://ihateregex.io/expr/date/

I just added the last "|([0-9]{10})" for the 10 digit number.